# No CSS for jquery_datepicker in Rails 3.2.x app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using [jQuery datepicker](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker) gem in a `Rails 3.2.x` app and the calendar looks like there is no CSS applied to it.

I have required all jQuery related JS files in my `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

I also followed the simple instructions in the ReadME for the gem.

I was under the impression that once I required it in my application.js, then everything should be included.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're not including the CSS assets as well. Simply including the JavaScript assets is not enough to get it styled.

As the `jquery-rails` README states:

> In order to use the themed parts of jQuery UI, you will also need to supply your own theme CSS (or use the jquery-ui-rails gem mentioned above).

Comment: Thnx Biggs :-P Damn length requirement.